# Java applet fails to load in Java 7 update

Tags: applet, java-7

Our application was working fine until we upgraded our PC to java 7 update. The application works fine in Java 6 but fails to run in Java 7.

I am testing with Internet explorer 7.

Comment: We need some more information. Error messages and some code, for example.

Comment: I have kept the applet in an iframe. while loading I get just the frame nothing inside..but when i test with java6 it runs fine.
please let me know if you want some more information.

Comment: Give an URL to the applet.

Comment: It cant be accessed outside..its restricted. Could you please tell me the reason why it fails in java 7 alone, works fine in all other versions till 6 though!?